# Android Global Search

Tags: android, xml, search, global, searchable

I'm trying to add my app to the global search in Android so users can search my app from their homescreen. I've followed the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html but it won't seem to work. When I test the app and go to the part of the settings where you see all the searchable apps my app doesn't show up. Here's some of my code:

The Mainfest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

This of course is within the  tag.

searchable.xml (res/xml/searchable.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:includeInGlobalSearch="true"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton"
    android:label="Holo Wikipedia Search"
    android:hint="Search Wikipedia" >
</searchable>
```

Please leave a commment if there's any more you want to see :)

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using string resources for the label and hint?

Instead of hard-coded strings, try something like this:

```
android:label="@string/label_string"
android:hint="@string/hint_string"
```